# Change default Scald legend or caption output

Tags: 7, scald

I am sure the setting must be somewhere, but I only want to have the title as a default caption, the author field is irrelevant and the people updating content have to delete it each time.

[image: Default caption appearance]

**Update:**

I have found that going to Administration > Structure > Scald > Image (/admin/structure/scald/image/player/full/image_figure) I am able to alter the caption for that player, but not for the default player.

I have also found a hook in scald.api.php hook_scald_player(), but this is used like an info hook and using hook_scald_player_alter() does not alter the value:

```
function mymodule_scald_player_alter(&$players) { // tried referencing
  $players['default']['settings']['caption'] = '[atom:title]';
  return $players; // tried returning
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you can alter the settings of players as much as you like, but it won't change the caption text because the pattern is hardcoded in the function `theme_sdl_editor_legend()` of the Scald module.

So we need to overwrite the output by something of our choice.

The previously mentioned theme function can be overwritten in your themes functions.php. Probably you use a Drupal Core or contributed theme as administrative theme, those template.php files you should not change. Thus the preferred method is below (a custom module).

Below you find a simple example of how to get rid of the "by" part in a custom module.
Effectively we just completely overwrite the output of `theme_sdl_editor_legend()` using an implementation of the `hook_scald_dnd_library_item_alter()` hook. You can change `$item['meta']['legend']` to any string you like using data from `$atom`.

```
/**
 * Alter a scald library item.
 *
 * Implements hook_scald_dnd_library_item_alter()
 *
 * @param $atom
 *   The atom object.
 * @param $item
 *   The scald library item.
 */
function MODULE_scald_dnd_library_item_alter($atom, &$item) {
  $item['meta']['legend'] = "
   <div class='meta'>
    <!--copyright={$atom->sid}-->{$atom->rendered->title}<!--END copyright={$atom->sid}-->
  </div>
 ";
}
```

Comment: Downvoter could you please explain why you don't like this solution? How can it be improved?

Comment: It could be improved by a better explanation, but I didn't down vote you, I am upvoting you.

Comment: @DrCord thank you for the feedback, I improved the explanation. Let me know if you still lack something.

Comment: Good job! Much appreciated for those future people who come here for info.

Answer (score 2):

When the site is personal, or images are simple, you don't need neither want a caption or elaborate caption below the image as it breaks the esthetics of content. One may even prefer to have them a

If you are using CKEditor, the Drag and Drop Library configuration page (`admin/config/content/dnd`) allows doing away with Captions (all of them) but not part of them:

```
[ ] Enable captions by default
```

One would expect that changing the display at `admin/structure/scald/image/display` would take care of it (dragging fields not desired to hidden) or on a similar fashion. But it does not work.

Bottom line is there are plenty of situations where captions are not desired for images.

There seems to be no easy way of having them not added by default other than hard code edit or hiding them via css.